How to built iOS app with type "Share" same app of soft 3utools install to iPhone
I need to build iOS app with "Share" type like 3uTools but don't know how to config build. help me please
[Image list iOS app from 3uTools][1]: https://i.sstatic.net/5YQAraHO.png


You should edit the post, rephrase the question and put the image.

Welcome to SO. Please familiarise yourself with how to ask a good question and provide a minimal reproducible example.

I don't have enough 10 reputation to post images
